# How to compare between two different propensity matching done on the same outcome and exposure, but with different baseline covariates?

Tags: propensity-scores, confounding

Suppose I use the same data (outcome and exposure) and I have a list of baseline covariates that I want to adjust for. But I am unsure of which covariates yield the best result from propensity matching.
Let us I decided to opt for two options.

1. Option A: Use baseline covariates from my prior subject matter knowledge (n = 10 covariates)
2. Option B: Use all the other baseline covariates (n = 100 covariates)

I used 1:1 greedy matching each time and therefore I have access to covariate balance before and after matching. Both results looks reasonable to me as per the Love plots (Covariate balance plots). However, I want to make an informed decision as to choose which model for my downstream analysis. Option A or Option B? I am looking if there is a quantified approach towards determining which option did the best job.

Answer (score 0):

In general terms, propensity score matching (PSM) should include all available covariates (excluding those creating logical fallacies) associated with the outcome (see for instance: https://rmdopen.bmj.com/content/5/1/e000953):

[image]

However, in your present scenario, you could could compute the mean of all standardized mean differences (SMD) for all covariates based on PSM using list of variables A (PSMA) and then mean SMD from PSM of list of variables B (PSMB), and then check (and pick) which one is smaller.